# how can i run the webpack compiler asynchronously or use a hook/promise/callback?

Tags: webpack

I am running webpack via node, not from the command line. After I run the compiler, I want to do some processing on the bundles it creates, however the files aren't available right away. If i run the same script again, with the bundles already written to the `.tmp` directory, everything runs fine.

*a contrived example*

```
webpack({output: {path: '.tmp'}}).run()

shell.exec 'ls ./.tmp'
    # > ls: cannot access './.tmp': No such file or directory
```

How could i either run the compiler asynchronously, or run code via hook/promise/callback?

Answer (score 1):

i discovered you can pass a function to `.run()` that will be called after the compiler is finished running. the documentation for requiring webpack as a module, is very lacking, and hard to find.